# How to use soap api?

Tags: soap-api, webservices, soap

Can anyone share me how to use soap  with example
Tried with rest. It is cool.

If someone can share step by step process to approach soap .

Answer (score 1):

The following Links gives you Step by step process about Webservice callouts using soap api and wsdl.

http://sriramp84.blogspot.in/2012/10/salesforceapex-callout-to-external.html

http://www.developer.com/net/net/salesforce-integration-with-.net-web-services-soap-api-.html

[WSDL SOAP UI salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23101/wsdl-soap-ui-salesforce)